# How does one remove all <li> tags from a parent <ul> tag?

Tags: jquery

Given:

```
    <ul id="myList" class="list-group">
      <li>Remove Me 1</li>
      <li>Remove Me 2</li>
      <li>Remove Me 3</li>
    </ul>
```

I would like to remove all of the li children from a parent ul, so that when i do:

```
    $("#myList").append("<li>New li 1</li>");
```

I end up with

```
    <ul id="myList" class="list-group">
      <li>New li 1</li>
    </ul>
```

Instead of:

```
    <ul id="myList" class="list-group">
      <li>Remove Me 1</li>
      <li>Remove Me 2</li>
      <li>Remove Me 3</li>
      <li>New li 1</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: and whats your problem?

Comment: `remove` is for removing elements. You want to remove elements. I don't see any problem here.

Comment: This is my favourite question.

Comment: this will work welll `$("#myList").html("").append("<li>New li 1</li>");`

Answer (score 96, accepted):

try this instead there is no remove i guess`$('#thickBoxProductLists').empty();`

Comment: there is a remove http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: yes but empty got the job done didn't she ???

Comment: i dont know which job. Saurabh did not mention what to do. I just mentioned that there is a remove function in jQuery ;-)

Comment: OK i THink you should try `$('#thickBoxProductLists li').remove();`

Comment: `$('#thickBoxProductLists li').remove();` will remove the element with that id and not only its children

Comment: @Fender: No, it will remove all `li` descendantes which should be fine.

Comment: @Felix Kling: oh... i just saw `#thickBoxProductLists`so you are all right :)

Comment: but why removing in the first class `hide()` is all you need

Comment: @Qchmqs: We don't know what the OP wants to do. `hide` and `remove` have their purposes.

Comment: I don't want to look stupid but i can't think of any use of remove in real life i mean give me a situation where i possibly want to remove something

Comment: removing unneccessary items so that they don't need memory, but you will only need that on special pages which are almost never reloaded (maybe googlemail or other pages like that)

Answer (score 7):

If you have only li elements inside your `ul` tag ,Jquery's `remove()` function is all what you want.

But if you have other text or etc, use `empty()` function.

Comment: `ul` elements are not supposed to have (non-empty) text nodes as children anyway.